# Origin of the verbal form of morph

Tags: word-usage

***[Morph](https://www.etymonline.com/word/morph)*** as a verb is a recent coinage, but as  as [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morphed&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmorphed%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows, its usage  literally shot up from the start and has increased constantly.

> Morph: as a noun, in biology, 1955; ***as a verb, in cinematic special effects, c. 1987,*** short for metamorphosis. (Etymonline)

also, from Vocabulary.com,  ***[morph](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/morph) :***

> As a verb, it has only been around since the 1980s, when computers allowed animators to make things change shape in an apparently seamlessly way.

It appears from the above source that the verbal form was coined by a screenwriter or a videogame developer in the ‘80s, which, given the increasing popularity of the term, was probably a very successful one.

I couldn’t find more details about its origin, so can anyone help pin down when and by whom this verbal form first used, given the relative short history of the expression?

Comment: the name of THE person?

Comment: @lbf - not necessarily, even though for recent coinages it is sometimes possible to find the name of the person  (writer, journalist etc.) who first used it. Btw, what’s  unclear about my question?

Comment: But as a *verb* (unlike the noun entry you provide) it would be a shortening of *metamorphose*. And that word has [apparently](https://www.etymonline.com/word/metamorphose#etymonline_v_32055) been around since 1570. Are you asking for when the *short form* first appeared?

Comment: @JasonBassford - that’s related but with different connotation and usage. The question is about “to morph.”

Comment: But your question doesn't make that distinction. (The text ***to morph*** doesn't appear anywhere.) I 'm also not sure that there's any significant grammatical distinction when it comes to the verb itself. *I* ***walk*** *to the store* versus *I am going* ***to walk*** *to the store.* The verb *walk* is still the same.

Comment: @JasonBassford - In my question I cited  two sources which specifically refer to the verb “***to morph***”. I don’t see what your problem is. 1)https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/morph 2)https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morph 3)https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/morph_1

Comment: @user240918 You're drawing an artificial distinction between the verb *morph* and its description *to morph*. When describing verbs, we often add *to* in front of them—but that's not how the *words* are spelled. If you look at the examples of the verb in your second source, none of them use the actual text **to morph**. The verb *eat* can be described as the verb *to eat* or the verb *eat*. They're not different things. Similarly, the verb *metamorphose* (from 1570) is still the verb *to metamorphose*. So, are you talking about the verb itself—or just the use of the short phrase *to morph*?

Comment: @JasonBassford - I didn’t draw any artificail distinction, please refer to the cited sources. ***To morph derives from metamorphosis***  but it is a recent form   with a more specific usage and connotation. Language changes and new forms are created. This in particular has been a successful one given its considerable increase in usage in recent decades. If you don’t understand the question, just move on!!!

Comment: The use of "morph" in a cinematic context might have been influenced by or reflected in the early Aardman Animations children's character [Morph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_(animation)) who appeared on the BBC children's art programme "Take Hart" from 1977.  I remember watching this programme with my then young son in the very early 80s and finding the name familiar even then. I couldn't swear to it but I feel that the verb form was already in fairly general use even before Morph appeared, does that sound right to other people of my age?

Comment: FYI, the word "form" means the opposite of what you seem to think; the noun and verb uses of *morph* have exactly the *same* form.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like like the etymology is a little more complicated, with "morph" as a verb also being used early on in a gaming context at least as far back as 1982:

> A staff of polymorph can help too if you morph him into something ‘easy’.
>   <sub>*Re; Killing Umbers* in *net.games.rogue* (Usenet newsgroup) 15 Sept.</sub>

The game they're talking about here is [Rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(video_game)) (1980), and staffs of Polymorph are used to [change monster type](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Rogue/Items), which was probably based off the [*Polymorph*](http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2014/05/spells-through-ages-polymorph.html) spells from the pen and paper role playing game Dungeons and Dragons or its predecessor, [Chainmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chainmail_(game)). Given that Chainmail was released in 1971, I wouldn't be surprised if there were earlier examples out there.

The OED doesn't have any other examples from before 1991. I was however able to find "morphing" in a computer graphics context in 1990:

> **Morphing** Animation created by changing the shape of an object through gradual metamorphosis.
>   <sub>[Amiga Resource](https://computerarchive.org/files/computer/magazines/compute%20amiga%20resource/Compute_Amiga_Resource_Vol_02_03_1990_Jun.pdf), June 1990</sub>

Answer (score 0):

First used by an artist, J. Karl Bogartte, when referring to his copy machine collages in the early '70s. He called this work "Photomorphosis" (the word abandoned by scientists and replaced with Photomorphogenesis). When he was working, he called the process "morphing" and making "morphs" - Never copyrighted.